# How to build a static library in g++

Tags: c++, g++, static-libraries

I have a file structure like this:

```
SS_STATIC
|---build
|      |----makefile
|
|---includes
|      |---multiply.h
|      |---divide.h
|
|---src
|      |---multiply.cpp
|      |---divide.cpp
```

I would like to create a simple static library to use in a project. What do I need to put in my makefile to achieve this? This is what I tried to do:

```
FLAGS= -I"../include"
lib_div_mult: multiply.cpp, divide.cpp
    g++ lib_div_mult -o divide.cpp, multiply.cpp $(FLAGS)
```

now I don't know how to use the `ar rv` command.

Answer (score 0):

Static libraries are not created through linking, rather they are simply an archive of the object (`.o`) files.

`make` has built-in support for building static libraries:

```
libdivmult.a: multiply.cpp divide.cpp
```

(it's conventional to start the name of the static library with `lib` and use the file extension `.a`).

Should be enough.